# Duplicate Book Titles using Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, duplicates

I was given a file that I have to find the duplicates and put them into a new text file.  That is the gist of what I am trying to accomplish.  Here are the directions I was given:
Your client owns a bookstore, and you will find attached; a text file called Samsbooks.txt with
titles of all the books in the store. Write and Print all the duplicate titles to a file called
SamsDuplicate.txt.
EXAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
Duplicate Books
Sam’s Bookstore 2021
Jack and Jill
Peter Pan
My Little Pony
```

Here is my code:

```
enter code here

//In this program, I will write and print all the duplicate book titles to a new file called 
SamsDuplicate.txt.

import java.io.*;

 public class bookstore {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //Printwriter object for the output file that is called SamsDuplicate.txt.
        PrintWriter duplicates = new PrintWriter("SamsDuplicate.txt");
    
        //Bufferreader object for the input file that is called SamsBookstore.txt.
        BufferedReader original = new BufferedReader(new 
FileReader("C:\\Users\\patti\\Desktop\\Patricks dcom101class\\CSIT 
 210\\SamsBookstore.txt.docx"));
    
    String begin = original.readLine();
    
    //This while loop will read each line of the SamsBookstore.txt file.
    while(begin != null) {
    
        boolean in_stock = false;
        
        //This Bufferreader object is for the output file SamsDuplicate.txt.
        BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("SamsDuplicate.txt"));
        
        String mid = output.readLine();
        
    //This while loop will read each line of the SamsDuplicate.txt file.
    while(mid != null) {
        
        if(begin.equals(mid)) {
            
            in_stock = true;
            break;
        }
        
        mid = output.readLine();
    }
    //This if statement is if the boolean is false and will also write line from SamsBookstore 
file to SamsDuplicate file.
    if(!in_stock) {
        
        duplicates.println(begin);
    }
        
    begin = original.readLine();
   }
    //Closing both files.
    original.close();
    duplicates.close();
    
    System.out.println("Duplicate Books");
    System.out.println("Sam's Bookstore 2021");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    }
 }
```

I cannot use HashMaps or anything of that nature since I have not learned about it yet.  I have tried putting in the last System.out.println line: my printerwriter (duplicates), my bufferreader(output), even the name of the new file I created called SamsDuplicate.txt none of them will display the duplicates.  Am I missing something here?  Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `Set`?

Based on your code, it seems that the `Samsbooks.txt` has a book name per line, right?

`Set` has a method [add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-), declared `boolean add(E e)`. It returns `true` if the element was added and `false` if it was not because it already exists in the collection.

If you cannot use `Set`, you can implement similar functionality by storing each book name in an array. You'll need to first check if the current book name is already in the array. If it is not, then resize the array +1 and add the new book name to the end.

Comment: Yes the text file is a book per line.  No, I cannot use set, we haven't learned it yet.  Would doing it as an array give me the output of the duplicates?

Comment: Yes, you can create a second array and add the duplicates to it. Sorry, I don't feel comfortable providing a solution with code because this sounds like a school assignment.

Comment: It is and creating an array for the duplicates never crossed my mind.  I was thrown off in the directions when it said "Write and Print all the duplicate titles to a file called
SamsDuplicate.txt. " made it sound like that file is what I should be displaying instead of an array. Thank you!

Comment: @PatrickO'Rourke One thing that might help here: you can't display a file or even an array. You can only display strings. To "display an array" you must turn it into some string representation and then display that string. Similarly for the contents of a file, you have to get strings that you can then display.

Comment: @PatrickO'Rourke As for solving the problem, I suggest you think about how you would do this by hand. Say I give you a list of books and you need to determine the duplicates in that list. What steps would you take to find them yourself?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice do you mean by highlighting the duplicates? i highlighted them in the file and is it as simple as doing a println for the duplicates?  I tend to overthink all these assignments I am given since I have only been working with java for 3 months.

Comment: @PatrickO'Rourke I mean if I gave you a 100 books on a piece of paper. What steps would you take to find the duplicates by hand?

Comment: If this answer and its comments solved your question, please consider checking it. It lets us know that we helped.